# SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql

I create my database and user `navid` in my shared server with `cpanel` (`databases -> mySQL@ Databases -> add new user`),and then selected ALL PRIVILEGES for user `navid`.
I was importing `mydatabase.sql` when I was confronted with this error.

---

how do i fix the error?  store procedure worked fine in `localhost`.

---

what is SUPER privilege?

```
Error
SQL query:
DELIMITER $$--
-- Procedures
--
CREATE DEFINER = `navid`@`%` PROCEDURE `d_answer` ( OUT `sp_out` INT( 11 ) , IN `sp_id` INT( 11 ) ) NO SQL BEGIN DELETE FROM `tblname` WHERE `a_id` = sp_id;
SET sp_out = ROW_COUNT( ) ;
END$$

MySQL said: Documentation
#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: @Ben - what do you mean?

Comment: i don't know how can i grant the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation in shared server

Comment: I was questioning why someone cowardly downvoted your question (ie. gave it a -1 without providing any feedback on the reason). I thought that was a worthwhile question.

Comment: @Ben - thank you Ben,you are a good man :) .

Answer (score 37, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_super) (my emphasis):

> The SUPER privilege enables an account to use CHANGE MASTER TO, KILL
>   or mysqladmin kill to kill threads belonging to other accounts (you
>   can always kill your own threads), PURGE BINARY LOGS, configuration
>   changes using SET GLOBAL to modify global system variables, the
>   mysqladmin debug command, enabling or disabling logging, performing
>   updates even if the read_only system variable is enabled, starting and
>   stopping replication on slave servers, **specification of any account
>   in the DEFINER attribute of stored programs and views**, and enables
>   you to connect (once) even if the connection limit controlled by the
>   max_connections system variable is reached.

Since you are already `navid` to the database, you do not need to set the `DEFINER` attribute in your stored procedure; adding this line is causing the error to show up. If you remove this statement, your procedure will be created and you won't get the permissions error.

You only need to set `DEFINER` if you are setting up the stored procedure for some other user, by default the stored procedure gets the same security context [as the user that is creating it](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-programs-security.html):

> All stored programs (procedures, functions, and triggers) and views
>   can have a DEFINER attribute that names a MySQL account. **If the
>   DEFINER attribute is omitted from a stored program or view definition,
>   the default account is the user who creates the object.**

Comment: Really? It is not necessary to use definer in my store procedure?

Comment: No, you only do that if you are setting the stored procedure on behalf of another user; and to do _that_ you need the `SUPER` privilege.

Comment: Check the definer, should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`

Answer (score 9):

I got the problem too and fixed it thus in MySQL Workbench.
In my case it is because the "Send to SQL Editor > Create Statement" has extra stuff in there that prevents from being used without modification.

Something like this:

CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED DEFINER=`schemax`@`localhost` SQL 
SECURITY DEFINER VIEW `viewName` AS SELECT ....

Change it to this:

CREATE VIEW `viewName` AS SELECT ....

Seems to work now, no need to update permissions.
**I am the only user of my database..

Comment: Thank You So Much.

Comment: Check the definer, should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue - on my local dev server it was fine but on my hosted server (through PHPMyAdmin) it gave me the above error.

Removing the definer attribute seemed to be the easiest way to fix the problem if you're happy with the definer being the current user.

Comment: Check the definer, should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`

Answer (score 1):

just remove the **DEFINER** attribute and with it's value, example:

```
CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED  SQL SECURITY DEFINER VIEW ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on default values, if emptying the definer field in phpMyAdmin or other programs won't solve, check the definer, should not be `username@localhost` unless explicitly needed, but `username@%`.